# How to detect "share" using actionscript?

Tags: facebook, actionscript

we all know its possible to make a share button for face book which allows users to share whatever item. but when we are directed to that page the user has two options. press the "cancel" button which of course closes the window, or to press the "share" button which then adds the item to the persons wall.

what i'm trying to do is determine if that share button has been pressed. see because when they press it i want my swf to trace out a message saying "thanks for sharing my item"

and while i can redirect them to the page i have no way of knowing if they shared it or not. my idea was to use an enter_frame event and try and see if any data was being sent via php. because thats what the button would be doing when pressed. but i haven't had any luck making that work.

here is the code so far. its a tutorial as the focus is at my problem:

```
import flash.net.navigateToURL; import flash.net.URLVariables; import flash.net.URLRequest; import flash.net.URLRequestMethod; share_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, shareClickHandler); function shareClickHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {     var varsShare:URLVariables = new URLVariables();     varsShare.u = 'http://domain.com/pageN.html';     varsShare.t = 'Title Page';     var urlFacebookShare:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php');     urlFacebookShare.data = varsShare;     urlFacebookShare.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;     navigateToURL(urlFacebookShare, '_blank'); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use static class for share.
Look at this:

```
package shvyrev.com.utils 
{
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

    public class ShareUtil 
    {
        static private var url:String;
        static private var feedFunction:Function;

        static public function shareFacebookExt(appID:String, title:String, titleLink:String, caption:String, description:String, imageSource:String, redirectUrl:String = '', feedBackFunction:Function = null):void
        {
            url = 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=' + appID + '&picture=' + imageSource + '&name=' + escape(title) + '&link=' + escape(titleLink) + '&caption=' + escape(caption) + '&description=' + escape(description) + '&display=' + 'popup' + '&redirect_uri=' + redirectUrl;

            feedFunction = feedBackFunction;

            try 
            {
                if (redirectUrl !== '' && feedFunction !== null) ExternalInterface.call('confirmPost', handler_confirm);
                ExternalInterface.call("window.open", url , "win", "height=400,width=580,toolbar=no,scrollbars=no");
            }catch (err:Error)
            {
                if (feedFunction !== null) feedFunction.call(null, 'facebook share unaviable');
            }
        }

        static private function handler_confirm():void 
        {
            feedFunction.call(null, 'handler_confirm')
        }
    }
}
```